# How to hide tab control when item source list is empty

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I have a WPF .NET Core application with a TabControl bound to an ObservableCollection for the TabItems. I would like the TabControl to be hidden when the ObservableCollection becomes empty, and I would like to display another panel in its place. Then, when an item is added back to the ObservableCollection, I want the alternate panel hidden and the TabControl reshown. How would I accomplish this, hopefully in XAML with as little code-behind as possible? I know I can do it in code-behind.

Below is the key section of the app. I have hidden the TabControl, and included a Border control to represent the Panel that I will show when the TabControl is hidden.

```
    <Window x:Class="TabTest.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabTest"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
        <Grid>
            <Border Name="emptyTabPanel" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}" 
                                BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" Margin="5,0,5,5" Visibility="Hidden">
            </Border>
            <TabControl Name="MainTabControl" Visibility="Visible">
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Label Content="{Binding Header}" MinWidth="60"/>
                            <Button BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Height="16" Width="15" Margin="15,2,0,0">
                                <Image Source="images/close.png" Height="8"/>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace TabTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<TabEntry> tabEntries;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tabEntries = new ObservableCollection<TabEntry>();
            MainTabControl.ItemsSource = tabEntries;

            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                tabEntries.Add(new TabEntry { Header = "tab " + i });
            }
        }
    }

    public class TabEntry
    {
        public string Header { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All ItemsControls provide a `HasItems` property that you can use in a Trigger. In contrast to a DataTrigger on `ItemsSource.Count` this also works when ItemsSource is not set at all.

```
<TabControl ...>
    <TabControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TabControl">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Style>
    ...
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a DataTriger in a Style.  Note that you need to remove `Visibility="Visible"` or the Setter won't be able to change it.

```
    <TabControl Name="MainTabControl" Background="Red">
        <TabControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TabControl">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ItemsSource.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Style>
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <!-- and so on -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper view model for this, rather than binding the tabs directly to the collection. That view model would include a `HasItems` property which you'll bind your `TabControl` visibility to, and an inverse property - say `IsEmpty` - which you'll bind the panel's visibility to.

Bind `ObservableCollection`'s [events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8#events) to listen to changes in item count and raise `PropertyChanged` events for your view model appropriately.

Comment: I know what you're saying. I was really hoping to keep this simple, and not have to get into full-blown MVVM. If no one comes up with a simpler solution, I will go that way.

Comment: There might be some way to achieve what you want in XAML, I honestly haven't looked very hard. But VM is just a tool, like XAML is. Why complicate matters where simplicity will suffice.